# What are these Japanese characters which look like an 'S' and a small 'n'?

Tags: kanji

What are these Japanese characters?

[looks like 'n'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdwpF.jpg)

[looks like 'S'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfMNV.jpg)

I have seen these characters in plenty of untranslated manga, but I haven't been able to find those two letters anywhere.

Does anyone know what Japanese characters they are supposed to be?

Comment: I think (not completely sure) it's そ and り.

Comment: Could the S-shaped one be a vertical 〜？

Comment: You shouldn't upload screen shots of single characters.  Even if (in this particular case) they're easy to read, it's easier to read characters in an actual linguistic context, so what you're doing is essentially making the question more difficult for no reason.  You can look up the "word superiority effect" for more information.  As an aside, these aren't letters, they're characters.

Answer (score 6):

The "looks like 'S'" character is most certainly the vertical writing mode variant form of either:

〜 U+301C WAVE DASH

or:

～ U+FF5E FULLWIDTH TILDE

Refs:

- [Japanese punctuation - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation#Wave_dash)
- [Tilde - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Japanese)

[image: U+301C & U+FF5E in vertical writing mode]

Comment: That software looks useful. How can I download and install it for Windows? Thanks.

Comment: [Unicopedia Plus](https://electronjs.org/apps/unicopedia-plus) is an Electron app available from its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/tonton-pixel/unicopedia-plus); there is no binary readily available for Windows, it would have to be built from source code, and it has only been successfully tested on macOS and Linux so far...

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, I would suggest providing more context for questions. Without the proper context, answers may be less accurate.

> The first one is almost certainly the hiragana り (ri).
>   [image]

As mentioned, more information would be helpful, particularly about the second one. I will edit my answer if more information is available.

**EDIT:** *See the answer by user34239 for information on the second character.*